Why is record class's bool Equal(R obj) a virtual method
From the spec:

The record type implements System.IEquatable<R> and includes a
synthesized strongly-typed overload of Equals(R? other) where R is the
record type. The method is public, and the method is virtual unless
the record type is sealed.

What is the real purpose of having the method declared as virtual when we can't really override it with user code in derived classes since it's auto-implemented by the compiler? What does the compiler's auto-generated implementation guarantee for records to work well that we couldn't live without otherwise?
return Equals((object)other);


The records can be inherited.

Because in a derived record, the Equals method may need to include additional checks, so it needs to be overriden.

Sweeper's answer is in sync with the current official docs which describe value equality:

For types with the record modifier (record class, record struct, and
readonly record struct), two objects are equal if they are of the same
type and store the same values.

that is however

If you don't override or replace equality methods, the type you
declare governs how equality is defined:

So, modifying slightly Sweeper's example by overriding the virtual property EqualityContract :
void Main() {
    Compare(
    new A() { Foo = "a"},
    new B() { Foo = "a", Bar = "c" }
);
}

public record A {
    public string Foo { get; set; } = "";
}

public record B : A {
    public string Bar { get; set; } = "";
    protected override Type EqualityContract => base.EqualityContract;
}

void Compare(A a, A b) {
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); // True
}

Here only the Foo part is evaluated between the two objects and it returns true. b.Equals(a) returns false though which is a bit confusing as evidenced ( and discussed in detail) in this and this questions.
My best attempt at conceptualizing the feature is that it just lets us extend the concept of same type (invariant) to be a type assignable to (covariant).
For example:
public record A(string FirstName) {}
public record B(string FirstName, string LastName) : A(FirstName) {
    protected override Type EqualityContract => base.EqualityContract;
}
public record C(string FirstName, string LastName, int Age) : B(FirstName, LastName) {
    protected override Type EqualityContract => base.EqualityContract;
}

var aRecord = new A("John");
var bRecord = new B("John", "Doe");
var cRecord = new C("John", "Doe", 33);


aRecord.Equals(cRecord).Dump(); // True -> C is assignable to A
aRecord.Equals(bRecord).Dump(); // True -> B is assignable to A
bRecord.Equals(cRecord).Dump(); // True -> C is assignable to B

cRecord.Equals(aRecord).Dump(); // False -> A is NOT assignable to C

This form of covariance works only from the actual object's runtime type, and not from the variable reference type, i.e.
A cRecord = ...
cRecord.Equals(aRecord).Dump() // will evalute to false

In my opinion, this has to do with the original implementation (following shortly) that relied on the virtual dispatch of object.Equals.
The most canonical explanation I could find for what EqualityContract is supposed to enable is from March 2020 when the typed Equals(R obj still hadn't been decided on and they used object.Equals for examples:
public abstract class Person // Root of hierarchy with value equality
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    protected virtual Type EqualityContract => typeof(Person);
    public override bool Equals(object other) =>
        other is Person that
        && object.Equals(this.EqualityContract, that.EqualityContract)
        && object.Equals(this.Name, that.Name);
}

public class Student : Person // derived class
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    protected override Type EqualityContract => typeof(Student);
    public override bool Equals(object other) =>
        base.Equals(other) // checks EqualityContract and Name
        
        && other is Student that // if other is just Person won't work
        
        && object.Equals(this.ID, that.ID);
}

There was some discussion in the issue as why not implement the type check in the base class with an approach similar to this.GetType()==other.GetType() which would have worked in preventing the base class for evaluating ONLY its state against an instance of a derived class and mistakenly returning true. The main response was:

Some people feel this is a niche scenario, and the compiler should
just generate a typeof(...) check directly. I don't know. I like
solving the whole equality problem of hierarchies. Having two values
agree that they have the same equality contract seems like it fully
addresses symmetry, while respecting the choice of derived classes ("I
want to be like my parent" vs "I am my own kind of thing"). I think
this approach (originally proposed by @gafter long ago) is super
elegant.

In June 2020 they had drafted typed Equals(R obj) for inheritance scenarios that have functionally the same behavior as today. I couldn't really find in all the meeting notes why they decided to make the methods effectively sealed virtual (you cannot override the methods in derived classes legally).
If we didn't have the EqualityContract feature and we just compared for exact type in the root record Equals(no user option for assignable/covariance), those methods could have really just been instance methods and not virtual. Using the example with A, B, C from above.
A aRecord = new A...
A bRecord = new B...

bRecord.Equals(aRecord); 
// this would use the A.Equals which could 
// have just checked for exact type match (between this and other) and returned false.

But with the EqualityContract overridable check in the root's A.Equals we could have it evaluate to true. A is not assignable to B, as B was to A from the first example, so that's no longer the original (already confusing to some) covariant solution. So they had to prevent this.
The way they did is with having the method be virtual so to trigger virtual dispatch where they could forward to a type checking obj.Equals to prevent the behavior:
// B's override of A.Equals that we cannot generate ourselves
public sealed override bool Equals(A other)
{
    return Equals((object)other); // let's say we have A object
}

// object.Equals that we cannot generate ourselves
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    // effectively preventing us from comparing
    // objects that are not assignable to B from
    // comparing to B at all

    return Equals(obj as B); // will evaluate to null -> false
}


Records can be inherited, and the compiler will override the strongly-typed Equals in a derived record, and that's why it needs to be virtual.
Consider
public record A {
    public string Foo { get; set; } = "";
}

public record B: A {
    public string Bar { get; set; } = "";
}

B inherits the Equals(A) method from A (in addition to its own Equals(B) method, of course), which B must override, because otherwise Equals(A) only compares Foo, which is incorrect when comparing two B instances.
If Equals(A) is not overridden in B, the below code would print "True" because only Foo is compared, which is quite unexpected if you ask me.
Compare(
    new B() { Foo = "a", Bar = "b" }, 
    new B() { Foo = "a", Bar = "c" }
);

void Compare(A a, A b) {
    // this calls the 'Equals(A)' overload!
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));
}


I think the OP's question might be why it's not possible to override public virtual bool Equals(A? a) in B. I actually wonder the same too.

@PedroCosta I think it is the same reason as why you're not allowed to explicitly override Equals(object). One needs to be very careful when implementing these Equals methods to ensure that they all do the same thing. Only allowing programmers to override the strongly-typed Equals makes it harder to make mistakes.

@Sweeper I thought it was to prevent something like this but couldn't find official justification of why it would be unexpected. The method cares about A and the part of A is identical between the two Bs, so they are "equal". When would this be a problem?

it also prevents children of A that have both the same EqualityContract wrt to A to not test equal from references of A where a.Equals(b1) and a.Equals(b2) would be true.

@IvanPetrov That's not what the contract of Equals is. You wouldn't expect ((object)someString).Equals((object)someOtherString) to only compare their object references, would you? Do you think that expression should only "care about the object part of string", and returns false just because the strings are not the same instance?

@IvanPetrov Another example would be a generic collection of things that derive from A. class SomeCollection<T> where T: A, and you create a SomeCollection<B> and add some Bs into it, and you ask if it contains some other instance of B. Wouldn't it be weird if it only considers the properties declared in A? Now the argument of "the method cares about A and the part of A is identical" doesn't apply.

@Sweeper where is the contract of Equals(T) for records stated? Because Equals works differently for ValueType, string and object. We can deduce what the contract is from experiments, but I haven't seen the contract stated explicitly and that having Equals(A other) as effectively virtual sealed is enforcing it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
